# self.presentedViewController won't clear even when it's dismissed, thus preventing interstitial AdMob ad from showing

Tags: swift, admob

Google gives a new error message "The provided view controller is already presenting another view controller" if self.presentedViewController exists. The problem is, self.presentedViewController seems to always exist even after dismissing itself!

code:

```
    print("printing presented view controller1: ")
    print(self.presentedViewController!)
    print("printing picker: ")
    print(picker)
    
    picker.dismiss(animated: true, completion: nil)

    print("printing presented view controller2: ")
    print(self.presentedViewController!)
    sleep(3)
    print("printing presented view controller3: ")
    print(self.presentedViewController!)
    
    // self.presentLoadingIndicator()
    
    if self.interstitial.isReady {
        print("presenting ad.")
        print("printing presented view controller: ")
        print(self.presentedViewController!)
        self.interstitial.present(fromRootViewController: self)
    } else {
      print("Ad wasn't ready")
    }
```

output:

```
printing presented view controller1: 
<UIImagePickerController: 0x7fe3c00c5c00>
printing picker: 
<UIImagePickerController: 0x7fe3c00c5c00>
printing presented view controller2: 
<UIImagePickerController: 0x7fe3c00c5c00>
printing presented view controller3: 
<UIImagePickerController: 0x7fe3c00c5c00>
presenting ad.
printing presented view controller: 
<UIImagePickerController: 0x7fe3c00c5c00>
2020-08-03 20:38:27.025517-0700 BeerVision[26634:3155513] <Google> The provided view controller is already presenting another view controller.
got into dismiss handler
```

As you can see, all of the printed view controller are the same object. How do we get rid of self.presentedViewController other than by dismissing? Shall I just forcibly point it to nil or something?

Comment: I tried a workaround by having 
        self.present(self.loadingAlert, animated: true, completion: nil)
then calling AdMob present on the loadingAlert, but unfortunately presentedViewController was still the same Image picker which was already dismissed. Also, "the provided view controller is not being presented". Furthermore I tried another workaround, passing the image picker view controller instead of top-level into the AdMob present. It says the view does not exist in the hierarchy (which makes sense because the user already dismissed it).

Answer (score 1):

Okay, I finally figured out that this might be an actual bug in Google's code because they assume the view isn't presentable as long as it has presentedViewController even though based on my debugging it could have a presentedViewController even after that presentedViewController was already dismissed (and in fact even after I presented a new view controller, somehow presentedViewController still shows the old one). Therefore I changed the version of my pod to a much older version of Google Ads. Here's what I did:

```
pod 'Google-Mobile-Ads-SDK', '7.53.1'
```

Then I was allowed to set the root view controller as "self" even when self has a dismissed presentedviewcontroller, and the ad shows up perfectly as expected.

There was still some finessing to make sure the ad doesn't get prematurely dismissed (unlike in Android apps, iOS interstitial ads will disappear if you kill their parent view, which is problematic if you wanted to display the ad while a "loading" progress bar is showing and the "loading" progress bar will eventually be dismissed while the ad is showing. I had to reprogram the code to avoid dismissing "loading" until the ad is not showing anymore)

Comment: Check your timing when dismissing your view. We had this same issue, we were trying to present a full screen ad in the unwind.onComplete but the parent view still had a value in the self.presentedViewController. We fixed this by setting a bool in the unwind.onComplete and then presenting the ad in the viewDidAppear of the parent. Also the last SDK version that worked for us was 7.55.1. Version 7.56.0 appears to require the self.presentedViewController to be nil.

Comment: version 7.53.1 is working for me as of today (11/18/20)

Comment: @mikemike396 This was a brilliant idea. Your strategy with placing a bool in unwind complete and then show the ad in viewDidAppear is the perfect workaround. You have to turn this comment into an answer.